# Static fields of derived class not initialized before they are needed in the base class

Tags: c#, static-variables

I'm trying to create a base class that can be derived from to make custom enum classes that potentially have several fields and methods. The base class keeps a list of all defined values for each enum type and a name variable for all values. The problem I'm running into is that the static fields of deriving classes are not initializing until I call on one of them directly due to the behavior of the CLR, but they need to be initialized in order to add themselves to the list of defined values of that enum type.

For example, the collection Day.Values will be empty unless I previously did something like:

Day today = Day.MONDAY;

Is there a way to ensure the static fields in Day will be initialized if I call on Day.Values even if I don't call on one of the fields first? Or, is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

```
public abstract class EnumBase<T> where T : EnumBase<T>
{
    private static List<T> values = new List<T>();
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return values.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    public string name { get; private set; }

    protected EnumBase(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        values.Add((T)this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Day : EnumBase<Day>
{
    public static readonly Day MONDAY = new Day("monday");
    public static readonly Day TUESDAY = new Day("tuesday");
    //...

    private Day (string name) : base (name) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to achieve?  I'm having a hard time following - you're not using or adding anything to `Day.Values` anywhere in your code and I don't see how `Day today = Day.MONDAY` would alter anything in `Day.Values`

Comment: Of course you can't use data from a derived class in the conductor of the base class. The best you can do is to call a method from the base class in the constructor of the derived class that will initialize the data you want.

Comment: @Saggio when `MONDAY` or `TUESDAY` is created, it will fire the `protected EnumBase` constructor, and add itself to the values collection.  edit-- or should I say 'supposed to'.

Comment: @impr0t ah of course, I missed the `EnumBase` constructor when I was looking at the question.  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using reflection to inspect the derived type for relevant fields.

Further, you can perform this initialization when `Values` is first accessed, deferring this work until it's needed and caching the result.

Here is an example:

```
public abstract class EnumBase<T> where T : EnumBase<T>
{
    static Lazy<List<T>> values = new Lazy<List<T>>(FindEnumMembers);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return values.Value;
        }
    }

    static List<T> FindEnumMembers()
    {
        Type derivedType = typeof(T);
        return derivedType.GetFields()
                          .Where(f => f.FieldType == derivedType)
                          .Select(f => (T)f.GetValue(null))
                          .ToList();
    }

    public string name { get; private set; }

    protected EnumBase(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Day : EnumBase<Day>
{
    public static readonly Day MONDAY = new Day("monday");
    public static readonly Day TUESDAY = new Day("tuesday");
    //...

    private Day (string name) : base (name) 
    {

    }
}
```

Access should work either way, since these are synonymous:

```
Day.Values
//or//
EnumBase<Day>.Values
```

Note again that these are synonymous, because this is the root cause of your original problem.  Calling `Day.Values` is actually interpreted as `EnumBase<Day>.Values`, and thus your static members of another type `Day` are not initialized by this call. By using reflection in `EnumBase<T>` and asking for the fields of the derived type, they will be initialized (if they have not yet been) as a side-effect of calling `GetValue` just like they would be if you had accessed them at that point statically.

Answer (score 0):

I had no time to test this, but here is an example of having each enum class as a singleton. (I hope it works....) :D

I took the static out of your base class and added it to the "Day" singleton so that different extensions of the class will not accidentally share data.

Singletons can be called from anywhere and create one instance of themselves.

ie

```
Day.method(); // From anywhere
```

Day.addEnum('Wednesday');

```
public abstract class EnumBase<T> where T : EnumBase<T>
{
    private List<T> values = new List<T>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return values.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    public string name { get; private set; }

    protected EnumBase()
    {

    }

    public string addEnum()
    {
        this.name = name;
        values.Add((T)this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

using System;

public class Day : EnumBase<Day>
{
    private static Day instance;
    private Day() {}

    public static Day Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Day();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    addEnum('monday');
    addEnum('tuesday');
}
```